# script or program to list variable names and values in memory for a Java program (memory snapshot)

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a Java program running in JVM. I need to find out at any moment what are the variables stored in the memory. I need to list their names and values. Can use any language or scripting to write this program.

I have used JMAP and JHAT to get a heap dump and see the dump values. But it does not give what I want.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a commercial profiler like YourKit.  If this doesn't give you what you want, I suggest you try to explain what it is you are looking for.

Comment: I have already used tools like Memory Analyzer and JHAT. They give me lots of information, but no list of variable names and values. Also, I need to generate these information programmatically. I want automatically a file will be created with the said values.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? i.e. why are you doing this because it sounds like there is a better way.

Comment: Actually I am doing a fault regression testing. I am running a program several times with different faults injected in each program in each run. Now I want to compare the memory usage of the programs to see the effect of the faults inserted. Hence, I want to compare the variable values stored in the memory for each program to see if any data consistency has happened due to the fault injection.

Comment: So you are injecting faults but cannot change the prgram to report those faults?  Why doesn't the program tell you what you need to know or be changed to tell you what you need to know?

Comment: I just need to see what is in the memory and compare the memory values from each run. For this I need memory snapshot.

Comment: There is no "just" about taking an entire memory dump of a program and searching around in hundreds of mega-bytes of binary data.  You can do this but how do you know the variable names are for the classes or instances you really want.  You will see any field with that name.  It is much easier to add a debug/print statement to report the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) is one of the best profilers in town, but is pretty expensive. And, while they might offer you a free trial period, that doesn't do you any good the next time you need to do similar testing on your next project.

I'd recommend using what the good 'ole JRE ships with: [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/). It has all the features you're looking for (inspecting variables/objects dynamically at runtime), as well as the ability to monitor heap/thread activity, perform heap/thread dumps and analyze them, and even has its own object query language (OQL) for query object values out of a dump based on certain criteria.

The downside is that it introduces a moderate performance overhead, so you would only want to run this in a non-production environment. (For low-overhead production monitoring using something like [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/) or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)). **Will JVisualVM's performance overhead affect how fast you code runs?** Yes. *But* since you'll be running it for each and every test case, all test cases will be affected equally.

So, it sounds like you want this as your basic workflow:

1. Start your app/JVM
2. Start JVisualVM
3. Start profiling ("Snapshot Mode") your app with JVisualVM
4. Run your next test.
5. Stop profiling your app
6. Do a heap and/or thread dump and save it off somewhere on your file system
7. If more tests, go back to #3.
8. Else stop your app
9. In JVisualVM, load each heap/thread dump one by one, possibly using OQL to fetch the objects/variables you are looking for, and comparing each test case's performance to the others

Good luck & HTH.